# Logical AND for checkboxes using CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I'm controlling events using CSS by implementing checkboxes like so:

```css
.box {
    display: none;
  }

  #step-1a:checked ~ .box {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<input name="step1-check" id="step-1a" type="checkbox">
<input name="step1-radio" id="step-1b" type="radio">
<input name="step1-radio" id="step-1c" type="radio">
<div class="box">Hello world!</div>
```

The CSS is used to guide the user through a form with multiple steps. The issue I'm having is that I'd like the form to require both the checkbox checked AND one of the radio buttons checked. Is there some way to incorporate a logical '&&' in my stylesheet to inforce this?

Comment: I was literally about to ask this - so strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, and you don't even have to alter your HTML!

Simply chain the **[sibling selectors (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)** together, and check that `#step-1a:checked` is followed by a sibling radio `input` that is also checked with `input[type="radio"]:checked`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}

#step-1a:checked ~ input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input name="step1-check" id="step-1a" type="checkbox">
<input name="step1-radio" id="step-1b" type="radio">
<input name="step1-radio" id="step-1c" type="radio">
<div class="box">Output</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hee Hee - I already posted that.... :) its a race in here with these solutions :)

Comment: What if, for example, the radio buttons are nested inside a div? Could I use #step-1a:checked ~ div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .box ?

Comment: @gavgrif - Yeah, honestly didn't see you had already written that though :) You beat me to the punch by a few seconds ;)

Comment: @CurtisUpshall -- Unfortunately **no**, as there's [**no parent selector in CSS**](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/), leaving you no way to 'break out of' the containing `<div>` in order to get back to `.box`. If `.box` were *also* inside of the child `<div>`, that would work :)

Answer (score 6):

Put the elements into a parent wrapper and use the :checked pseudoselector on both the checkbox and the radio button and the general sibling combinator to ensure that they are both picked up wiith the .box div.

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper input[type= 'checkbox']:checked  ~ input[type= 'radio']:checked ~ .box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input name="step1-check" id="step-1a" type="checkbox">
  <input name="step1-radio" id="step-1b" type="radio">
  <input name="step1-radio" id="step-1c" type="radio">
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of input[type="checkbox"] or input[type="radio"] can I use an ID or class?